Brownian motion conditional characteristic function
Let $(W(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be Brownian Motion. I am trying to find, for $0 \leq s <t$, $E(e^{W(s)}|W(t))$.
I can see two approaches to this. One, using TOK and independence of increments and rewriting as follows: $E(e^{W(s)}|W(t))=E(e^{W(s)-W(t)} \cdot e^{W(t)}|W(t))=e^{W(t)}E(e^{W(s)-W(t)})=e^{W(t)}e^{\frac{t-s}{2}}$. At the end I also used the distribution of increments (under time reflection).
The other approach is to directly use the conditional distribution of $W(s)|W(t)$ and use the characteristic function of that. But this leads me to the answer $e^{\frac{s}{t}W(t)}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{2}s(1-s/t)}$.
I don't know what goes wrong with either of the two approach and thus don't see where the mistake lies. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

The first approach is incorrect because $W(t)$ and $W(s)-W(t)$ are not independent.
For the second approach, you don't need to use the characteristic function. Here is an adaptation of the "conditional approach" (which interestingly looks similar to the first approach!) that simplifies the calculation
$$B_s = \underbrace{\left(B_s -\frac{s}{t}B_t\right)}_{\perp B_t} + \frac{s}{t}B_t$$
In fact, $\frac{s}{t}B_t$ is the projection of $B_s$ onto the space generated by $B_t$ and $B_s -\frac{s}{t}B_t$ is the Brownian bridge following the normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,s(t-s))$.
Then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(e^{B_s}|B_t) &=e^{\frac{s}{t}B_t}\mathbb{E}(e^{B_s -\frac{s}{t}B_t}|B_t) \\
&=e^{\frac{s}{t}B_t}\mathbb{E}(e^{ \mathcal{N}(0,s(t-s))}|B_t) \\
&=e^{\frac{s}{t}B_t}e^{ \frac{\color{red}{s}(t-s)}{2}} \\
\end{align}$$
PS: I think you missed the term in red color.
